# Terraform - How to add port number at the end of a resource name?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Silly question, but struggling to add the port number at the end of a resource for my Terraform build. Here is my resource:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "dns_record" {
  provider = aws.mgmt
  zone_id = data.aws_route53_zone.hosted_zone.zone_id
  name    = "${var.subdomain}.dev.${data.aws_route53_zone.hosted_zone.name}"
  type    = "CNAME"
  alias {
    name                   = data.aws_elb.test.dns_name:3000
    zone_id                = data.aws_elb.test.zone_id
    evaluate_target_health = true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add the port at the end of the `name` under the alias block, but I'm getting this error:

`On main.tf line 24: An argument definition must end with a newline.`

Which makes me assume this is a syntax error?

How would I be able to manually add the port at the end of the name?

EDIT: Closing this thread because Route53 doesn't handle ports.

Comment: Can you do this in the AWS console? If not, then you won't be able to do it in Terraform.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking how to do string interpolation in HCL2, which would be with the following syntax:

```
name = "${data.aws_elb.test.dns_name}:3000"
```